# Minimum cost path to visit a set of points in a given order exactly once?

Tags: algorithm, math, dijkstra, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

#### The Problem:

We are given a set of N points on a 2D plane, we have to find a path which visits all the points in the order 1-2-3....N and comes back to 1 such that the time taken is minimized. We can move one step to north,east,west or south which takes 1 unit of time. We cannot visit an y of the N points more than once except for 1, which we cannot visit more than twice.

N <= 100
The x and y axis of every point is <= 1000000

([This](http://usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=106) is the complete problem statement which appeared in a past USACO contest)

#### My Algorithm:

The x and y axis of the points can be very large but there are just <=100 points so, we change x-axis of the points so that when the are arranged in ascending order of their x axis the difference between the x axis of the adjacent points is 1. We do the same for all the y axis of the points.

Now we find the shortest path from point 1 to 2, from 2 to 3, ... and from N to 1 without visiting any of the given points other than the source and target. We cannot use a straightforward bfs to find the shortest path from, because the distance from a point x,y to a point x+1,y is not 1, but is the original value of x+1 minus the original value of x. So I used Dijktra's algorithm with a binary heap to find the shortest path.

But this algorithm does not work for half of the [testcases](http://usaco.org/current/data/delivery.zip), it outputs a solution larger than the correct solution.

Why is this algorithm wrong? How do we solve this problem otherwise?

Comment: "we renumber the points so that when they are arranged in ascending order of their x axis the difference between the x axis of the adjacent points is 1" - There's no guarantee you'll be able to do so for every input. There may be large gaps in the points layout on the X axis.

Comment: @EyalSchneider I meant that I number the points again starting from 1 such that the gap between adjacent points is 1, I have edited my question, maybe its more clear now.

Comment: I see. However, the same procedure applied on Y axis will produce a different numbering of the points, possibly conflicting with the previous numbering. How do you deal with this?

Comment: @EyalSchneider I think thats where I go wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The x and y axis of the points can be very large but there are just <=100 points so, we change x-axis of the points so that when the are arranged in ascending order of their x axis the difference between the x axis of the adjacent points is 1. We do the same for all the y axis of the points.

This essentially means you remove “unused” coordinates. But that will cost you space to maneuver. Take the following example:

```
4
1 1
3 3
3 2
1 2
```

The shortest path here takes 8 steps. Assuming positive x is east and positive y is north, that best path would be `ennESwWS`, with capital letters indicating arrival at the next farm.

```
   /--2
   |  |
4--|--3
|  |
1--/
```

Now if you do your compression scheme, then you'll remove the y=2 column, and in effect will be left without any column where you could pass from farm 1 to farm 2 without visiting farm 3 or 4. So I see no gain from this compression, but lots of trouble.

> So I used Dijktra's algorithm

On what graph? If you use Dijkstra on the farms only, you'll be in trouble, since you have to take the non-farm locations into account. If you take those as well, things should work, as far as I can see. Except for the compression up front.

What you *can* do if you want to keep this idea is to compress consecutive ranges of empty rows or columns into a single one. That way, your graph will stay reasonably small (201 rows and columns max), but where there is space to manaeuver around farms, your graph will represent that fact.

I guess I'd use a “detour metric” for Dijkstra: every step which brings you closer to the distance has zero cost, while every step that takes you away has cost one. In the end you can take the detour cost, multiply it by two (since every step you take away is also one more step you have to take towards your goal) and add the Manhattan distance of the end points (which is the zero detour cost) and you are back at your original cost. This is basically the idea from A*, but with the performance (and existing implementation) of Disjkstra.

Comment: thank you everyone for the answers. Now I understand my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If you compress this

```
..2
...
3.4
...
1..
```

to this

```
.2
34
1.
```

then you increase the length of the path from 1 to 2 because 34 constitute a spurious obstacle. You could compress multiple empty rows/columns to one empty row/column instead of none.

Answer (score 1):

My thinking is: when is the distance from point `i` to point `i + 1` not the Manhattan Distance? It seems to me that the only scenario for that is when there is a full horizontal or vertical block (or both), e.g.,

```
        (i+1)                  X    (i+1)           (i+1)
                              X
      XXX XXXX                 X                   XXXX
         X                      X                     X
       i                    i   X                  i  X
```

I haven't coded anything yet, but perhaps it would be useful to scan for either block when calculating the route to the next point, and calculate the minimal detour if a block exists.

Comment: These blocks will likely appear less linear than your examples suggest, instead forming a dense 2d collection of obstacles. I guess that in those cases, identifying blocks in any reasonable fashion might be harder than simply computing detours.

Comment: @MvG Thank you for your comment. I was thinking, if I had a catalog of objects (linked points) and their bounds, I could check the bounds against the deltas of `i` and `i + 1`. If a block is found, compute the shortest 'walk around'. Does that seem feasible? By the way, how can Dijkstra be used, if the order of visitation is already given?

Comment: What is given is the order in which the farms are visited, but not the order in which the fields in between are used to form a path. So for every pair of farms, Dijkstra can be used to compute a path between them, possibly using a detour.

Comment: @MvG Thank you for elucidating. Without the proposed compression, would using Dijkstra be impractical for large intervals between farms, that is, too many choice paths to compare?

Comment: It might be. If Dijkstra is used with the naive step count metric, it will search in all directions and thus suffer severe problems due to empty space. Even with the detour metric, it will explore many more path alternatives, but only a linear amount per detour step involved, not quadratic. My main reson to suggest it was that this is closest to what the OP had tried, so although I'm not sure whether I'd have used that if I were to tackle the issue from scratch, it seems close to his approach and therefore most useful to learn from.